# R Package for Treatment Effect Analysis?

Tags: r, treatment-effect

I could not find a package in R about Treatment Effect Analysis.

So is there a R package about Treatment Effect Analysis?

This means, estimating the average treatment effect, average treatment effect on the treated using different methods, including algorithms such as k-nearest-neighbour matching, caliper-matching and things like that?

I found single packages about k-nearest neighbour matching and matching itself (e.g. [matching](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/Matching.pdf) of [FNN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FNN/FNN.pdf)), but I could not find a comprehensive package about treatment effect analysis.

Comment: how about `multcomp` package, regarding parametric models: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multcomp/index.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package looks very promising

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nonrandom/vignettes/nonrandom.pdf

but I´ve sofar mostly used the MatchIt package.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other packages to check out might be `ri` (randomization inference), `MatchIt` (provides various matching algorithms), and `experiment` (some basic ATE and LATE methods).